# Change rake tests between environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rakefile

I have a Ruby on Rails application that first goes through Jenkins where it is tested with the command `rake` and then sent to a testing environment where different tests are run.  I want to be able to use the `rake` command for these tests as well.  Basically, I want `rake` to run one set of tests in Jenkins and then a different set of tests when it is on the test server.  Is there a way to to set some variable that will tell the Rakefile, or `rake` itself, to switch to another set of tests?

Comment: Is this with rspec or normal rails tests?

Comment: @PierrePretorius Normal rails tests.  They are the ones created when running "generate scaffold"

Answer (score 0):

If you use normal rails tests, look at [this](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html) or the example below:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test_set_one) do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.test_files = FileList['test/test*.rb']
    t.verbose = true
end
```

Or if you are using rspec look at [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task) or the example below:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:test_set_one) do |t|
    t.rspec_opts = '--colour --format documentation'
    t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec'
end
```

You place the code above in rake tasks and then run 'rake test_set_one'.

Note:  Additionally you could look at the [ci_reporter](https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter) gem since you are using jenkins.